# rails 3 refined search

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, search, rest, cookies

I have a rails app. Homepage searches the movies database and displays the results in the results page for the search query.

Now, in the results page there are a list of movies (say 5) and the results page displays the attributes of the movies in the left side bar.

For example,

=================Movies results page================

### Left-side-bar

### Genres

Comedy(link_to)
Horror(link_to)

### Languages

English(link_to)
German(link_to)

### Results set

1 Anger management 
 2 American pie
 3 Evil dead
 4 Grudge
 5 Du riescht so gut

=====================================================

Now, after the first search, my search controller has a @movieid array which has those 5 movieids(mentioned above). And the left-side-bar has the filters to filter this further.
Using the @movieid array i listed the movies in the results set.

If i click on the link "comedy", I want the results page to show only "1. Anger management" and "2. american pie".

If i click on the link "german". It should only display  "5. Du riescht so gut". Thats it.

Right now, 
Im confused of the following options,
1. Im thinking of passing the genre_id and @movieid array through the link_to as parameters. 
2. Use cookie[:store] to save the @movieid array 
3. Store the @movieids in database and retrieve.

I dont know how to handle this. Remember my @movieid array can contain 100000 ids as well.

Help me with the best practice and performance.

Thanks!

Edit:

Can i use Mysql Views to store the result set? problem is what happens if a 100000 users are searching at the same time, that many views will be created?, is it ok?. What is the good practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, I did great!

Answering to my question:

1. From first main search page, if I run a search query, on the movies table and get 300 records as a result from 5000 movies in the table then I dynamically create a view in the mysql database from rails method, AR::Base.connection.execute() which holds the movie_ids of the 300 searched movies.
2. Now moving on, in the second page if the user filters 300 results based on language or genre, I narrow down my search, doing a search on the created view and not the MOVIES table again. This is done by getting the language_id and genre_id from the url after passing it to a link_to helper.
3. I get a session_id from every browser and append an alphabet in front of that id which will be used as my view name.
4. If the user visits the home page or gets past the search page and finds the exact product, I will drop my view and i will keep a timeout to drop my view say 1 hour and every day I will drop the views created the day before.

I heard from Ryan that persisting an User search is a good practice. I was interested in that as well. Now I think I have implemented it. Please hit me with all the negatives in my approach, Im trying to run a company here.

Thanks!

Edit:

Forgot my gratitude to Ashitaka. 
Of course I have added will_paginate gem. Its working alright.

TIP: In will_paginate, if you are listing out 83 movies with :per_page => 10, then you wont be able to display the total number of movies in the first page of 9 pages(10+10+....+3). If you wish to do it like Movies(83). Then,  @movies.total_entries.to_s helps.

Thanks to you too!

Answer (score 0):

Since you can have 100000 different movies, you need to implement pagination in your rails app. This is made easy with the `will_paginate gem`. Here's an example:

```
# movies_controller.rb
def index
  @movies = Movie.search(params[:q]).order('name').paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 15)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
  end
end
```

And then in your view:

```
# index.html.erb
<%= form_tag movies_path, :method => 'get' do %>
  <div>
    <%= text_field_tag :q, params[:q] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
  </div>
<% end %>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Movies</th>
  </tr>
  <% @movies.each do |movie| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= link_to movie.name, movie %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
<%= will_paginate @movies %>
```

Searching and filtering is definitely a thorny issue. It's really hard to explain in detail such a complicated thing, so I will simply point out to the incredible Railscast that explains how to do what you want.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/240-search-sort-paginate-with-ajax

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have seen that railscast it did not help. In that railscast Ryan talks about search and sort and paginate. In episode 111, advanced search form, he talks about storing the results set in a search resource.Im looking for something like that. If I get more clarity on that approach, I will be good to go.